# How can I obtain an XML file with web services using SOAP in a Java Web application?

Tags: java, html, xml, web-services, soap

Hi I've done some research, but I still can't solve my problem. I have to obtain a value from my [bank](http://indicadoreseconomicos.bccr.fi.cr/indicadoreseconomicos/WebServices/wsIndicadoresEconomicos.asmx?op=ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML) and print the value. They provide a web services site with the following code (already replaced the variables w/ the correct values)

> The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /indicadoreseconomicos/WebServices/wsIndicadoresEconomicos.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: indicadoreseconomicos.bccr.fi.cr
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML xmlns="http://ws.sdde.bccr.fi.cr">
        <tcIndicador>317</tcIndicador>
        <tcFechaInicio>14/05/2015</tcFechaInicio>
        <tcFechaFinal>15/05/2015</tcFechaFinal>
        <tcNombre>Bove</tcNombre>
        <tnSubNiveles>S</tnSubNiveles>
    </ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Here's what I've done so far

```
    public class ParseTest {

    public static void parse() throws IOException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {
        String fileRequestInput = "src/parsetest/XMLBanco.xml";

        File xmlFileRequest = new File(fileRequestInput);
        File file = new File(fileRequestInput);

        FileInputStream fstreamRequest = new FileInputStream(xmlFileRequest);

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = null;
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
        Document document = null;
        try {
            docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = docBuilder.parse(fstreamRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAILED");
        }
        System.out.println("Request xml generated Parsed succesffully ");
        System.out.println(document);

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        //initialize StreamResult with File object to save to file
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
        System.out.println(xmlString);


    }

}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
        <ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML xmlns="http://ws.sdde.bccr.fi.cr">
            <tcIndicador>317</tcIndicador>
            <tcFechaInicio>14/05/2015</tcFechaInicio>
            <tcFechaFinal>15/05/2015</tcFechaFinal>
            <tcNombre>Bove</tcNombre>
            <tnSubNiveles>S</tnSubNiveles>
        </ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

How can I parse the response and print the response value?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: see if they have WSDL file, then you can generate java client code from it and then you can use its methods to get the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way also

```
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage(
            new MimeHeaders(),
            new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlInput.getBytes(Charset
                    .forName("UTF-8"))));

    SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();

    NodeList returnList = body.getElementsByTagName("ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML");
```

then you can loop on the returnlist